# Is it okay to ask about a story's writing style?

Tags: discussion, support

I'd like to ask a question about an apocalyptic short story titled "Episode Seven: Last Stand Against the Pack in the Kingdom of Purple Flowers." My question concerns the author's writing style, namely in that 75% of the story has no sentence endings (about 15 pages; it's literally a text wall).

Is this on-topic here? I've looked in the FAQ, but it doesn't list a category that fits this question. It does seem on topic, though. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the story, but if it is sci-fi/fantasy related, then *the story* would be on-topic.

Beyond that, it depends on your specific question.

If you're looking for a *discussion* on the author's writing style, then the *question* would be off-topic (or more correctly, out-of-scope) for the main site.

Again, without knowing specifics of what it is you're looking for, you may find a better audience in something like [the writers stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but you may find someone knowledgeable in our own chat room.

Comment: Also worth noting that if what you're asking for is a list of (or examples of) books or writers with a similar style, it's also likely going to be considered off-topic.

Comment: I'm guessing my question would be on topic, but that I'd get a better response at Writers.SE. Thank you!

Comment: @Emrakul It should be noted that writers.se does not allow "Questions seeking to interpret or analyze an existing work." Again, without knowing what it is you're looking for, I can't really say for sure that they'll be able to help either